# iOS Read file lines into array

Tags: ios, arrays, file

I have a file containing a couple thousands words on individual lines. I need to load all of these words into separate elements inside an array so first word will be Array[0], second will be Array[1] etc.

I found some sample code elsewhere but Xcode 4.3 says it's using depreciated calls.

```
NSString *tmp;
NSArray *lines;
lines = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"testFileReadLines.txt"] 
                   componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSEnumerator *nse = [lines objectEnumerator];

while(tmp = [nse nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` has been deprecated.

See Apple's documentation for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile%3a)

Instead use `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error`

Use as follows:

```
lines = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"testFileReadLines.txt"
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                      error:nil] 
            componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

**Update:** - Thanks to JohnK

```
NSCharacterSet *newlineCharSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"testFileReadLines.txt"
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineCharSet];
```

Comment: For generality you should use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`, viz.: `NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"testFileReadLines.txt"                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; NSArray *lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];`.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/apps/fixed-stringwithcontentsoffile-is-deprecated-error/). You might have to use an updated method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Gave Aadhira the correct answer for was slightly more complete.